# Provide hint about which windows for a function to use?

Tags: window-splitting, dedicated-windows

I like follow-mode which I have recently discovered.

But I would like to avoid completely losing my window setup within a frame.

Is there a way to label a window as usable by a function?

Comment: Would it be simpler to just use `winner-mode` and undo the window config change when you're done?

Comment: It took me 30 mins thinking, but you are totally right, thanks!